# How do I ensure a table exists in EF Core without using migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm writing a quick prototype project. I don't want to use EF migrations because I don't really understand them yet. The app imports data from a file into a DB. If the schema changes, my strategy will be "drop the tables and let EF rebuild them".

This works OK for adding data at startup, but I had trouble deciding if I *needed* to build the DB. For example:

```
var inputCount = parsedData.Items.Length;
var dbCount = _itemsContext.Items.Count();
if (inputCount != dbCount)
{
    // Do updates/inserts
}
```

Since the table doesn't exist, I can't query for a count. I could handle the exception but that felt a little messy. I just needed EF to create the table if it's not there. Everything I read walked me through adding migrations to the project but it feels like a feature I didn't want.

(I couldn't find a clear duplicate of this with the questions my use case generated. Now that I know the answer I can find questions that discuss it, but I hope this post helps guide someone that way.)

Answer (score 0):

The `DbContext` type has a `Database` property that gives you sort of backdoor access to things EF manages. It has a convenience method `EnsureCreated` (also an async implementation) that will ensure the table exists when the DbContext is configured.

Credit to [this EF tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) for explaining this and a handful of other exotic initializaton scenarios.o

Based on some other things I've read it seems this makes adding migrations later impossible, and perhaps `Database.Migrate()` does the same thing more safely. So have an idea whether you want migrations at all before you do this (but if you plan on using migrations, it seems silly to be doing manual initializations?)